# Creating FTP user via PHP

Tags: php, bash, ubuntu

is this task possible on ubuntu?

I have managed to create vhost via php, I need to create ftp user via php. We are trying to assign a specific directory to internal user who created account via web registration.

I have done this on windows by using filezilla server, where xml can be edited and refresh can be called via php. I need to replicate this for linux.

Thanks

**Update:**
`joe:$1$LX/3.F60$bYdYwsQOYIaWq.Ko.hfI3.:500:101::/home/ftpusers/joe/./::::::1000:10485760::::::`

This is the file passwd, well i tried to add another user following the above format, it works, however the same password hash doesn't work for second account.

I need to get to able to set it password as they specify or without any password. How would I achieve either one of that?

Comment: if your FTP server has commandline support to add users you can just use one of the PHP exec function.

Comment: do you know any of those for linux that has commandline support as you state?

Comment: What FTP server are you currently running? I don't want to recommend anything as you should not choose a server just based on the fact it supports commandline, you need to take into consideration speed, security, etc.

Comment: Its not actually a problem since its only for internal usage and only handful of people requires it. So, any ftp would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install PureFTPD by running from commandline:

```
sudo apt-get install pure-ftpd
```

Then follow the directions on the Ubuntu documentation page for setting up the group, folders, etc:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PureFTP

This is the command that will create a new user however it would be difficult to pass the passwords to the commandline:

```
sudo pure-pw useradd joe -u ftpuser -d /home/ftpusers/joe
```

So it would be best to create one starting user to generate the users config file located in /etc/pure-ftpd/ Since you said this is for internal use and you did not really care about security you can change the permissions of the file so you can edit it with PHP. Check out it's format and just have PHP add a new user section to it with the appropriate values. If I recall it is an XML file so using PHP's XML or DOM functions would work great with it.

---

**Update In Regards To Below Comments:**

According to PureFTPD:

> Passwords are hashed with the best one-way hash function your system
>   supports. Hashes are tried in this order: Blowfish, MD5, multiple DES,
>   simple DES.

Since your string starts with $1 which is for crypt() using MD5 that is what it ended up using. To get a password encrypted do this:

```
echo crypt('YOUR_PASSWORD', '$1$LX/3.F60$');
```

The $1 specifies to use the MD5 hash as that is what your system defaulted to, the $LX/3.F60$ part inside the $'s is your salt.

Comment: Thanks, `sudo pure-pw useradd joe -u ftpuser -d /home/ftpusers/joe` do it have to be sudo? how do i supply root password to php in case password is needed for root?

Comment: Please see my answer, about creating a starting user so you can see the XML file format and then having PHP just edit the file as you said you had previously did for Filezilla.

Comment: hey do you have any advise on how to insert password or create user without any password?

Comment: Post your XML in your question as an UPDATE: at bottom with the sensitive info X'ed out. Are you asking how to add the password using PHP or add the whole user section to the file using PHP? Also for no password that would be pretty much the same as allowing anonymous access.

Comment: updated the question, thanks alot for helping me out. i need to make it work without password or with correct password as they specify. When i created another user using php as the format, it works (username can login) but the password doesn't work

Comment: I'll be back online again tomorrow if you have anymore problems. It's past 2am here and a girl has got to sleep, so later. =o)